# Apache Cordova device is ready

Tags: android, apache, cordova

I'm new to Apache Cordova and of course already have a problem/question.
I'm trying to make "Hello world" example from "Apache Cordova programming4" book.
I've got index.html file with the source of my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>

  <head>
    <title>Hello World #2</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height" />
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script>
      function onBodyLoad() {
        console.log("Entering onBodyLoad");
        alert("Body Load");
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
      }
      function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("Cordova is ready");
        navigator.notification.alert("Cordova is ready!");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="onBodyLoad()">
    <h1>Hello World #2</h1>
    <p>This is a sample Cordova application.</p>
  </body>

</html>
```

Then I'm making my app with `cordova create test www.cordovaprogramming.hello hello`.
Adding android platform with `cordova platform add android`.
And building it with `cordova build android`.
Testing it with Genymotion emulator. 
When my app loads i have "Apache Cordova device is ready" screen, but then nothing else happens.
Can someone explain to me where i'm making the mistake? 
I checked my config.xml file but everything is okay there.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you added the dialog plugin. 
Do this `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs` then try building the app.

navigator.notification.alert is dependent on this

Comment: Yes, I have it but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see the alert "Entering onBodyLoad" ??

Comment: No, just the splash screen. Like this one
https://alastaira.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/image2.png

Comment: `I've got index.html file with the source of my app` from your screen shot, it looks like you haven't 1) deployed the rebuilt application or 2) have not placed the index.html in the www/ folder of the cordova project and rebuilt / deployed.  In this case you are still seeing the default index.html file from the www/ folder.  If you have adb setup with Genymotion, you should be able to build + deploy with `cordova run android`

Comment: make sure that path of `cordova.js` is correct and check the log.

Answer (score -1):

Delete everything pre written including the css files.
I mean the pre written content which is calling a function on pageload to put the cordova logo in screen.

Comment: I've deteleted everything. Now I'm seeing just the text - "Apache Cordova Connection to Device Device is Ready".